# Rails Will_Paginate throwing undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been having trouble with will_paginate based on an example from Michael Hartel's Ruby on Rails book 9.3.3.

Here is my views/professors/index.html.erb:

```
    <% provide(:title, 'All Professors') %>
<h2>All Users</h2>
<%= will_paginate %>
<ul class="users">
  <% @professors.each do |professor| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to professor.lname, professor %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

and the professors controller:

```
  def show
    @professor = Professor.find(params[:id])
    @professors = Professor.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

I keep getting the: undefined local variable or method `will_paginate' for #class.... error.

From what I've seen Hartel's version is a bit different then what the will_paginate docs say to do they have:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

In the controller and

```
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

on the render page.  I've tried that too and I get an undefined method error.
Also tried the variable in parenthisees (which I have seen some answers on here suggesting).

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the template for the index action and the controller for the show action. You also appear to have `<%= will_paginate %>` twice both without anything passed in. Can you update your question.

You need to move your `@professors` assignment to `def index` and not `def show` and then it should work when going to `localhost:3000/professors` or whatever your path is setup as.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm quite new to Rails... As far as the <%= will_paginate %> twice with nothing passed in, I'm just going off or what Hartel has in his book Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Web Development with Rails

Comment: `@professors = Professor.paginate(page: params[:page])` 
should be in `def index` not show

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm still having a "undefined method `paginate'" error.  '  def index
   @professors = Professor.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
' is what I've changed it too.  You mentioned that nothing is getting passed into the <%= will_Paginate %> I left that the way it was again I'm just going off the book if I should pass in @professors let me know.

Comment: no I checked into will_paginate more and it seems like it would know what to do if just included like that.

Try swapping paginate for `page(params[:page])`

Comment: and just as a sanity check, do you have `gem 'will_paginate'` in your gemfile and ran `bundle install`?

Comment: 'page(params[:page])' just changes the error to "undefined method `page'"   I uninstalled the gem and reinstalled it just to make sure, it seemed as though I actually had two versions installed so I cleaned that out and reinstalled.

Comment: do you have it listed in your gemfile or are you just installing via the command line?

Comment: It's installed in the gemfile.